# Segregate an array of 0s and 1s

Tags: java, array, sorting

I think that my code contains a lot of if and else statements that are probably not required.I suppose that this code could be condensed to a shorter form where the logic applied would look clearer than it does now. 
Suggestions are welcome and any help in refactoring would be highly appreciated.

```
public class Segregate{
    public static void doSegregation(int[] a){
        int i = 0;
        int j = a.length-1;

      while(i<=j){
        if(a[i]==a[j]){
          if(a[i]==1 && a[j]==1){
            j--;
          }
        else if(a[i]==0 && a[j]==0){
            i++;
        }
    }
    else{
        if(a[i]>a[j]){
            int temp = a[i];
            a[i] = a[j];
            a[j] = temp;
            i++;
            j--;
        }   
        else if(a[i]<a[j]){
            i++;
            }
         }
      }
   }

   public static void main(String[] args){
      int[] a = {1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1};
      System.out.println("Array before segragation : ");
      for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++){
         System.out.print(a[i]+" ");
      }
      System.out.println();
      doSegregation(a);
      System.out.println("Array after segragation : ");
      for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++){
        System.out.print(a[i]+" ");
       }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Why not using simple `Arrays.sort(a)`?

Comment: Then what's the point of solving the question?

Answer (score 3):

With the premise that you're not allowed to use `Arrays.sort` It'd be more succinct to write your own sorting method.

All you really need to do is initialize an array of the size, count the 1s and set that many positions from the end to 1.

This takes advantage of the fact that integers in java are initialized to 0; the resulting solution becomes straightforward.

Try it yourself, then look at this implementation:

```
public class Segregate {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] a = {1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1};
    System.out.println("Before segregation: " + join(a, ", "));
    System.out.println("After  segregation: " + join(segregate(a), ", "));
  }

  private static int[] segregate(int[] onesAndZeros) {
    int[] segregated = new int[onesAndZeros.length];
    int end = segregated.length - 1;
    for (int count = countOnes(onesAndZeros); count > 0; count--) {
      segregated[end--] = 1;
    }
    return segregated;
  }

  // Obviously only works in this specific case.
  private static int countOnes(int[] onesAndZeros) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int n : onesAndZeros) {
      count += n;
    }
    return count;
  }

  private static String join(int[] nums, String delim) {
    StringBuilder joined = new StringBuilder();
    for (int num : nums) {
      joined.append(delim).append(num);
    }
    return joined.substring(delim.length());
  }
}
```

**Output:**
[image: Implementation execution output]

Comment: And here I was trying to improve his actual algorithm ... you make it sound so trivial. I like it!

Answer (score 2):

I had some fun simplifying your method and came up with 2 solutions. Both use the same idea though. First update the `i` to point to the first `1`, next update the `j`index to point to the last `0`. If `i` isn't greater than `j` yet change the `0` and `1`.

The cutest solution looks like this:

```
    int i = 0;
    int j = a.length-1;
    while(i<j){
        if(a[i]==0){
            i++;
        } else if(a[j] == 1){
            j--;
        } else {
            a[i++] = 0;
            a[j--] = 1;
        }
    }
```

The other solution looks like this:

```
    int i = 0;
    int j = a.length-1;
    while(i<=j){
        while(a[i] == 0 && i < j){
            i++;
        }
        while(a[j] == 1 && i < j) {
            j--;
        }
        if(i>=j){
            return;
        }

        a[i++] = 0;
        a[j--] = 1;
    }
```

The second one is unnoticably more performant in that it doesn't keep checking that the `a[i]` isn't `0` while we're updating the `j` index.

I'd say both are readable anyway so it doesn't matter much which implementation to use.

---

small extra note is that you can also print arrays using `Arrays.toString(a)`. This then looks like this:

> [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1]